# Xpath - как получить текст?

Tags: xpath, google-spreadsheet

буду благодарен за Ваши ответы.
(Говорим про Xpath, но в идеале под Google Sheet)

**И так:** У меня есть Xpath которым я получаю ссылку со страницы - `//a[contains(@href, 'ukrinform.com')]/@href")`, чтобы проверить по своему списку страниц или ссылка еще на месте.

Но я бы хотел еще получить текст, в котором находится эта ссылка.

*Пример:* Текст на сайте в блоке div: "Остатки кукурузы - 1200 штук. Подробнее: ukrinform.com."
И вот я хотел бы по ссылке ukrinform.com получить весь текст из блока div.

Подскажите, возможно ли это вообще и как можно было бы это сделать? Искать по тексту или еще по чему? (Сайт разные, привязаться к классу или какому-то параметру не получится).

Comment: Xpath так, про Google Sheet не знаю `//div[a[contains(@href, 'ukrinform.com')]]/text()`

Comment: Согласен с @splash58. Теперь вставляем выражение XPath в Гугл-формулу: `=IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[a[contains(@href, 'ukrinform.com')]]/text()")`, где A1 содержит URL страницы-источника.